# 'the page has expired due to inactivity please refresh the page' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to solve this..
when I am registering in register page after submitting form I show given screenshot.
I tried too much from given in stackoverflow community but  failed..
earlier I use this it was working fine...
but from some days it's down
I am tried from trying too much possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this error is because the

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Is not added inside the `<form> </form>` tag.

But the registration form from Laravel should have the `{{ csrf_field() }}` as a standard

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens.. please suggest me else..

Comment: Well, i really cant. like the post showing its really unclear what the exact problem is.. Post pieces of code etc

Answer (score 0):

Add this to form

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: It should be underscore and not hypen `csrf_field()`

Comment: I used {{ csrf_field() }}, but CNT work...